# Check if a message has been deleted in discordjs

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a bot in discordjs and I'm trying to check if the interaction.reply message has been deleted or not to avoid "Unknown Message" Errors

Answer (score 1):

using a `try-catch` you can catch the error if the message was deleted

```
try {
  const message = await interaction.reply('message');
  console.log('Message not deleted');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Message deleted');
}
```

Comment: this doesn't really do anything since you're not deleting the message.